# How to create closure with specific typealias in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm using the swift package [OnboardKit](https://github.com/NikolaKirev/OnboardKit) and it requires a specific closure type that I cannot figure out. 
The class `OnboardPage` requires a type `OnboardPageAction` for the parameter `action`.

```swift
public typealias OnboardPageCompletion = ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)
public typealias OnboardPageAction = (@escaping OnboardPageCompletion) -> Void
```

```swift
OnboardPage(title: "Title",
            description: "description",
            action: action)
```

This is my latest attempt, I tried several variations along those lines.

```swift
let action: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> ()) = {_,_ in
    print("help")
}
```

XCode fails with the error message:

> Cannot convert value of type '(Bool, Error?) -> Void' to expected
>   argument type 'OnboardPageAction?' (aka 'Optional<(@escaping (Bool,
>   Optional) -> ()) -> ()>')

What am I doing wrong here? Is the mistake in my closure definition or in the way I use it in the OnboardPage() call? Thanks :)

(I learned details about closures here [Closures Swift How To](https://learnappmaking.com/closures-swift-how-to/), but I am not able to define the right closure type that the package expects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the context, I guess that the purpose of the `action` parameter is to allow you run some code when an `OnboardPage` is presented. This "action" might take some time (it might not finish when `action` returns), so it gives you a completion handler parameter that you can call to indicate that what you want to do is done.

If you just want to print Hello, you can just call the parameter after you printed hello to indicate that you finished what you want to do:

```
OnboardPage(title: "Title",
        description: "description",
        action: { completion in
            print("Hello")
            completion(true, nil)
        })
```

or simply

```
OnboardPage(title: "Title",
        description: "description") {
            print("Hello")
            $0(true, nil)
        }
```

The first argument indicates whether the action is successful, the second contains an optional error for when it fails.

Comment: aaaah that makes a lot more sense than what I tried! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

The declaration of an action should look like this to match the defintions provided:

```
let action: OnboardPageAction = { (_ closure: ((_ success: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) in
    print("action")
}
```